# How to upgrade kile2.1 beta 4 to kile-2.1.3 in ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: kile, upgrade

I want to upgrade **kile 2.1 beta 4** to Latest  stable version **kile 2.1.3** in *'Ubuntu11.04'*. Will there any problem if I upgrade it ?
My second question :
I have **kile-2.1.3.tar.bz2** file. How do I install it through terminal or any other way ?

Comment: If you don't know how to extract a tarball (in this case `tar xjf kile-2.1.3.tar.bz2`), you make not want to install by hand.  The `README` contains pretty standard build instructions, however.  (I'd uninstall your system-installed version first.)

Comment: Are there any features you absolutely need in kile 2.1.3? You would be still on texlive 2009. I think that's more of a problem.

Comment: ubuntu 11.04 had already [reached end of life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) hence stick with some 12.04 LTS version. Try installing `.deb` files at [launchpad built files for Natty Narwhal](https://launchpad.net/~kile/+archive/2.1-daily/+build/3900834) via [gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/)

Comment: There is a Ubuntu Stackexchange sister site http://askubuntu.org which is better suited for questions  about installing and updating Ubuntu packages. (The exeption is (La)TeX, e.g. TeXLive, itself)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sudo apt-get install kile--upgrade`.  Why don't you upgrade Ubuntu to 12.04 or even 13?

If the above works, you wont need the tar ball.

To extract the file, you can also do tar `tar jxf filename.tar.bz2`

I don't know if the file is called kile from the terminal you may need to check that.

Comment: I am not interested to upgrade ubuntu 12.02 or 13. Because,there  is internet connection problem(i.e., **INTEX SPEED 3G Installer.deb** file of my intex modem is not installing there. )